# How to select and print a specific JSON value using Python GET Request

Tags: python, json, get, python-requests

I am attempting to select an save a specific 'identifier' value(392861) from a JSON url file after retrieving the JSON using a GET request:

```py
getBooking = s.get("https://www.goodlifefitness.com/content/goodlife/en/book-workout/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/workoutbooking.GetWorkoutSlots.7.2020-12-15.json")
```

I would like to store this specific 'identifier' value so I can send this value as part of a separate POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific? Which "identifier" are you trying to access?
Let's assume you want to access the `dayOfWeek` tag for each workout, then you can do something like this:

```
workouts_list = getBooking.json()["map"]["response"][0]["workouts"]
for workout in workouts_list:
    print(workout["dayOfWeek"])
```

You can do the same thing for other parameters as well by just replacing `dayOfWeek` to any of the tags available on the JSON response.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get a "identifier" for a specific day. For example, I want to get the "identifier" of "392940" which is located in the first block of entries. I replaced "dayOfWeek" in your example with "identifier" but it stored and printed out all of the results from every block in the list:   392940
393250
392660
393116
392661
393117
393634
393703
393316
393427
393036
393118
392861
393119
392941
393635
392942
393037
393317
393636
392943
393251
392862
393318
392662
393704
392663
393705
393038
393319

Comment: @skeller then you don't need to loop through them. You can just do `iden = workouts_list[0]["identifier"]`

Answer (score 0):

The following code retreived the information I was looking for.

workouts_list = getBooking.json()["map"]["response"][0]["workouts"]
iden = workouts_list[0]["identifier"]

print(iden)